# jqgrid v4.4.4 - `{dataUrl:}` is ignored in Single/Advanced Search but correctly read in Search Toolbar/Form Edit. Bug or misconfiguration?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

- jquery: v1.9.1
- jqgrid: v4.4.4

I had succesfully populated the dropdown list in *Search Toolbar* and *Form Edit* with data retrieved from the server via the property `dataUrl`, however the same expected list doesn't appear for the same column in *Advanced Search* form.

Can anybody confirm this issue with `jqgrid` v4.4.4?
Did I misconfigure `jqgrid`?
Any suggestion would be helpful! :-)

In the below code:

- `searchoptions:{dataUrl:}` is ignored in *Single/Advanced Search*
- `searchoptions:{dataUrl:}` is correctly read in *Search Toolbar*
- `editoptions:{dataUrl:}` is correctly read in *Edit Form*

Here is the grid configuration:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.search, {recreateForm: true});

$("#school").jqGrid({
    height: 'auto',
    url: "lib/CSchoolAjax.php",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['ID', 'Location'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'school_id',
        index: 'school_id',
        width: 30,
        fixed: true,
        align: "center",
        search:false,
        hidden: false
        },{
            name: 'location',
            index: 'location',
            width: 80,
            align: "center",
            editable: true,
            edittype: 'select',
            editoptions: {
                dataUrl: "lib/CSchoolAjaxLocation.php",
                sopt: ['eq']
            },
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                dataUrl: "lib/CSchoolAjaxLocation.php",
                sopt: ['eq']
            }
        }
    ],
    sortable: true,
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pager: '#pager_school',
    sortname: 'school_id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    multiselect: false,
    caption: "Schools",
    editurl: 'lib/CSchoolAjax.php',
    hiddengrid:true,
    autoencode: true
})
.navGrid('#pager_school', {
    edit: true,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search:true
    },{
        width: 'auto'
    },{},{},{
        width: 'auto',
        multipleSearch:true,
        multipleGroup:false,
        //recreateForm: true,
        closeOnEscape: true
    },{
        closeOnEscape:true
})
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager_school', {
    caption: "",
    title: "Select/Reorder Columns",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    onClickButton: function () {
        $("#school").jqGrid('columnChooser');
    }
})
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pager_school", {
    caption: "Search",
    title: "Toggle Search Toolbar",
    buttonicon: 'ui-icon-search',
    onClickButton: function () {
        $("#school").filterToolbar({
            searchOnEnter: false,
            stringResult: true,
            defaultSearch: 'cn'
        });
    }
})
.trigger('reloadGrid');
```

The script "CSchoolAjaxLocation.php" returns

```
<select>
<option value=“1”>Location One</option>
<option value=“2”>Location Two</option>
..
</select>
```

Comment: jqgrid calls "CSchoolAjaxLocation.php" in Search Toolbar but not in Advanced Search form. According to [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config), they use a common search option as of jqgrid v3.5. Any idea?

Comment: jqgrid expects html code by default in return for `dataUrl` ([source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L353))..

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: ajaxso is undefined` at [grid.common.js, line 343](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L343)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Single Field and Advanced Searching* need the property [`ajaxSelectOptions`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) to be explicitly defined.